# Git + Jenkins - Release branch deployment

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration

In Jenkins, is it possible to select a release branch and deploy?  Release branch will be cut from master branch.

Release branch will be cut from master branch ,when QA is done with testing. This branch needs to be deployed (CI) to stage and Prod.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell Jenkins to watch a git repository for updates to trigger a build.

That mechanism allows for setting an expression for which branches to watch, and that can be used to achieve what you need here by setting it to match only your release branch.

Enable git support in Jenkins, and look at the configuration for the deployment job.